# HTML: is there any way to make clickable <td> o <tr> tags?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is there any way to make clickable `<td>` or `<tr>` tags?

Comment: What does `o` mean? Did you forgot to type `r` after it?

Comment: By "linkable" do you mean "clickable"? As in, they behave like anchor tags?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: sorry i meant clickable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<td><a href="foo">bar</a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, but imagine i give a padding to my <td> tag. If i move the mouse cursor into the cell you can see clearly that the <td> is not clickable, but just the word "bar"...

Comment: @user, `td { padding: someValue; } td a { display: block; margin: -someValue; padding: someValue; }` You may also want to add `text-decoration: none` to the `td a`.

Answer (score 5):

```
<td onclick="window.location = 'index.html';">cell content</td>
```

index.html above can be any URL or internal page link. Note: the mouse pointer does not turn into a pointing hand when you mouse over the cell using this javascript method, but clicking on the cell does take you to the URL.

Comment: <td onclick="window.location = 'index.html';" style='cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;'>cell content</td>

Answer (score 3):

To turn non-link tags *into* links, use [@Lie Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953470/html-is-there-any-way-to-make-linkable-td-o-tr-tags/3953483#3953483)'s answer and put an `a` into the element.

To be able to link *to* an element:

Use an `a`

```
<a href="#idOfTheElement">Link to the element</a>
```

and a named point:

```
<td id="idOfTheElement">contents</td>
```

Comment: Cool. Is that a new feature? I thought you needed an anchor tag with a name (not just any tag with an id).

Comment: @Thilo, it seems to work in all the newer browsers (including IE), but I'm not sure when it was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><a name="foo"/>bar</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<td>`s can have a JavaScript `onclick` event.

Other than that, putting an `<a>` into the table cell, and giving it a fixed width to fill the table (you need to make it `display: block` for that) is the most reliable way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you mean:

```
<td id="yourcell">Just a useless cell</td>

...
<a href="yourpage.html#yourcell">link</a>
```

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to make it using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#tableid tr').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if(href) {
        window.location = href;
    }
 });
});
```

If you want make all the cells are clickable you need to mention "td" in click function.